# Visual Studio Code: How to have both Debug window and Explorer window open together?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm new to Visual Code and I have a small question.

[image]

You have two buttons circled in red line. The first button opens the Explorer window and the second circled button opens the Debug window.

I want to have both of these windows open. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible as of VSCode 1.13

A feature request for showing multiple panels was tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3360) but the issue has been closed as as-designed. If you are passionate about the problem, please [file a new issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) to see if thinking on this has changed in the past year

Answer (score 1):

V1.43 will have the ability to move various views, like `Variables`, `Watch` and `Callstack` from the sidebar to the panel (it works nicely in the Insiders' Build v.1.43).  Demo:

[image: move debug views to panel]

See v1.43 release notes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#easier-moving-of-even-more-views with a demo gif of **dragging** views to and from the panel.

and this setting:

> We've introduced a new command to make moving views easier
>   with the keyboard: View: Move Focused View
>   (`workbench.action.moveFocusedView`).
>
> And finally, this is a preview feature. So, in case you get into a
>   state that you can't fix, there is a command to reset all views to
>   their original locations: View: Reset View Locations
>   (`workbench.action.resetViewLocations`).