# How do I move the debug menu to the footer or problems view in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to move the debug menu bar to the bottom of the application or into the problems view? It is anchored to the top of the screen.

[image: debug]

FYI I found that docking it is an option and I describe how to set that option in an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are a few issues about this on vscode github, for example see [summary of issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52490)

There is an extension available to move the debug menu bar to the status bar which looks good:

[StatusBar Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-statusbar-debugger)

[image: StatusBar Debugger demo]

-----  Update  -----------

In v1.42 and 1.43 it is now easy to move various debug view to the panel.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#easier-moving-of-even-more-views and [VS Code - toggle search icon in Activity Bar, move from panel or back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058584/vs-code-toggle-search-icon-in-activity-bar-move-from-panel-or-back/50065112#50065112) and especially

[Visual Studio Code: How to have both Debug window and Explorer window open together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183547/visual-studio-code-how-to-have-both-debug-window-and-explorer-window-open-toget/60427518#60427518)

> **Easier moving of even more views**
>
> Last release, we had just a taste of relocating views to the panel. In
>   this relase, this experience has been expanded to many more views. You
>   can now move many more views such as the debug views or the new
>   timeline view. You can also now move them into other viewlets in the
>   sidebar. For example, perhaps you'd like to move the Open Editors view
>   into the SCM viewlet. You can do all of this by dragging the views and
>   dropping them in the desired location in the Activity Bar or Panel.
>   The gif below highlights a few examples.

[image: release notes image]

> We've introduced a new command to make moving views easier
>   with the keyboard: View: Move Focused View
>   (`workbench.action.moveFocusedView`).
>
> And finally, this is a preview feature. So, in case you get into a
>   state that you can't fix, there is a command to reset all views to
>   their original locations: View: Reset View Locations
>   (`workbench.action.resetViewLocations`).

Answer (score 32):

It looks like you can dock or hide the debug tool bar:

> To hide the debug tool bar change the "debug.toolBarLocation" setting to hidden.
>
> Either **floating** in all views, **docked** in the debug view, or **hidden**.

Docking is better than floating and hidden. Adding the extension mentioned in the other answer is also helpful.

Comment: I needed that for so long! Thank you

Comment: From now on, you can also show the debug toolbar in the command center. Just add an entry to `settings.json` as `"debug.toolBarLocation": "commandCenter"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the debug toolbar to appear in the Command Center (requires Window: Command Center).
Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings and enter:
`"debug.toolBarLocation": "commandCenter"`

[Allow the debug toolbar to show in the command center](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192592)